# Did any Apollo missions have backup parachutes?

Tags: apollo-program, reentry, parachute

NASA's Apollo modules, the ones that went to the moon, had a fairly standard-for-the-time reentry method: Hit the atmosphere at the right angle, deploy a parachute after things are done burning up, and land gently upon the ocean.

Here's the main problem I can see: That parachute *has* to work. Otherwise, you have some fairly serious problems - such as water being like concrete if you hit it going very fast. And the Apollo modules where going *very* fast.

Did any of the Apollo missions include a backup parachute in case the main one didn't deploy properly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The apollo command module had three parachutes and two of the three would have been sufficient to slow the capsule sufficiently for a survivable landing.  However, this redundancy would not have protected against certain failure scenarios where the parachutes failed to deploy properly or multiple chutes failed due to a common cause, such as collision with debris.

[image: Apollo 15 descends with two good parachutes into the Pacific Ocean on August 7, 1971]

<sup>Apollo 15 descends with two good parachutes into the Pacific Ocean on August 7, 1971 (source: [Wiki on Apollo 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_15), image: NASA)</sup>

Additional reference: [Chapter 8 - Collision Avoidance Systems, 8.2 - Descent and Landing Systems, **Safety Design for Space Systems**](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZwD8uTpXet4C&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=apollo%20command%20module%20parachute%20redundancy&source=bl&ots=l_s4t0g_cs&sig=q5BqxWTq_BzJLXYLXWwlZoz1fPE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8nlpUoyaN4HW2AXkrID4DA&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=apollo%20command%20module%20parachute%20redundancy&f=false), 2009 Butterworth-Heinemann, by Gary E. Musgrave Ph.D, Axel Larsen, Tommaso Sgobba

Comment: "Guess we're going to find out whether this thing can really splash down with two chutes, boys."